# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input line 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, syntax-error

Hi there I am trying to figure out what is going wrong. I am getting the error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in line 1

which is

```
 var itemList = new Array();
```

A snippet of the code is included

```
var itemList = new Array();

$( document ).ready(function(){
var $newItem = $('#newItem');
var $itemList =$('#itemList');
var itemTouchStart;
var itemTouchEnd;
var itemTouchStartX;
var itemTouchEndX;

if( window.localStorage) //when application starts check if there is data
{
    itemList = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('itemList'));
}

if(null !== itemList)
{
    for (i=0;i<itemList.length; i++)
    {
        var itemNew = '<li data-key="'+ itemList[i].key +'"><span>' 
+itemList[i].item +'</span></li>';
        $itemList.append(itemNew);
    }

}
else
{
    itemList = new Array();
}
```

Comment: I think we need the whole code, because the error can be `});` missing at the end.... or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line number of the error is wrong. The problem is at the *end*, you never close the function you're passing into `ready` or the call to it. Add `});` at the end.

If that's missing only because you quoted a

> ...snippet of the beginning of the code...

...then the answer is that there's nothing wrong with line 1 that's apparent from your question. Weird errors like that can sometimes be down to invisible characters in the source, but I would expect to see an illegal character error rather than unexpected end of input. Unexpected end of input is pretty much what it says: You have a control structure of some kind open and haven't closed it when the parser reaches the end of the code text.

---

I find the [Meteor JavaScript parser page](http://jsparse.meteor.com/) is quite handy for diagnosing syntax errors.

Comment: Now you're telling me there's an error at line 1 of the error message? :)

Comment: Yes i was missing an }); at the end. :)